# Scala Pattern Matching returns expected type but generates type mismatch afterwards

Tags: scala, types, pattern-matching

I have the following scala object definition:

```
case class RecursiveSettings (
    var recursiveFrom: Int,
    var recursiveTo: Int,
    var nonRecursiveFrom: Int,
    var nonRecursiveTo: Int,
    var betweenReach: Int,
    var scoresamephrase: Boolean
    )
```

and I'm trying to get the variables from an ArrayBuffer:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

def main(args: Array[String]){
    var settings = List("","1", "2", "0", "0", true)
    var newsettings = new ArrayBuffer[Any]

    println(settings)

    settings.foreach {a =>
        val z = a match{
            case "" => 0
            case s : String => s.toInt
            case _  => a
        }
        newsettings += z
    }
    println(newsettings)

    var result = new RecursiveSettings(0,0,0,0,0,true)
    println(result)

    for (i <- 0 to (newsettings.length - 1)){
        println("newsettings_i", newsettings(i))

        val x = newsettings(i) match{
            case y : Int => y
            case y : Boolean => y
            case _ => 0
        }
        println("x:", x)
        i match{
            case 0 => result.recursiveFrom = x
            case 1 => result.recursiveTo = x
            case 2 => result.nonRecursiveFrom = x
            case 3 => result.nonRecursiveTo = x
            case 4 => result.betweenReach = x
            case 5 => result.scoresamephrase = x
        }
    }
}
```

If I comment out the i match statement and do a simple type match:

```
for (i <- 0 to (newsettings.length - 1)){
        println("newsettings_i", newsettings(i))
        val x = newsettings(i) match{
            case y : Int => "Int"
            case y : Boolean => "Bool"
            case _ => 0
        }
        println("x:", x)
```

the code compiles, runs and I get:

```
List(, 1, 2, 0, 0, true)
ArrayBuffer(0, 1, 2, 0, 0, true)
RecursiveSettings(0,0,0,0,0,true)
(newsettings_i,0)
(x:,Int)
(newsettings_i,1)
(x:,Int)
(newsettings_i,2)
(x:,Int)
(newsettings_i,0)
(x:,Int)
(newsettings_i,0)
(x:,Int)
(newsettings_i,true)
(x:,Bool)
```

But when I add the i match statement back in I get a lot of complaints of this type:

```
~/match.scala:44: error: type mismatch;
found   : AnyVal
required: Int
            case 0 => result.recursiveFrom = x
```

Can someone please help me to understand:

1. Why does the simple type match produce the desired result, but this is not carried through to the object?
2. What can I do to correct my code?

Thanks in advance, this has had me banging my head for hours!

EDIT

Ok so building on the info from @Alex Savitsky and @Jakub Zalas (thanks guys) I've substantially modified the original code to what I hope is something more functionally orientated which can deal with mixed init value types:

```
object matcher2{
def main(args: Array[String]):Unit = {

    val init = Array("",1, "4", null, "0", false)
    matchf(init)
}
def matchf(args : Array[_] ) : RecursiveSettings = {
    val settings : RecursiveSettings = args.map{
        case "" => 0
        case "true" => true
        case "false" => false
        case b : Boolean => b
        case s : String => s.toInt
        case i : Int => i
        case null => 0

    } match {
        case Array(recursiveFrom: Int, recursiveTo: Int, nonRecursiveFrom: Int, nonRecursiveTo: Int, betweenReach: Int, scoresamephrase: Boolean) =>
        RecursiveSettings(recursiveFrom, recursiveTo, nonRecursiveFrom, nonRecursiveTo, betweenReach, scoresamephrase)
    }
    println(settings)
    settings
}
}
```

Being new to Scala (and Java) from Python I'm still struggling a fair bit with the functional and static typing aspects, so any comments / suggestions gratefully received.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To follow up on the suggestion in @JakubZelas's answer, this can be done much more simply by pattern matching the list: `val first::second::third::fourth::fifth::Nil = List("","1","2","3",true)` and then defining a function to transform the strings (call if `f`) and just defining `RecursiveSettings(f(first),f(second),..., fifth)`.

Comment: By the way, check this Alvin Alexander´s post https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-why-make-mutable-collections-invariant-in-scala

Comment: Very useful as a starting point @hoyland, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the arguments to the appropriate types on the fly, and then match on the whole collection at once:

```
// assuming your args is an array of ["", "1", "2", "0", "0", "true"]
val settings: RecursiveSettings = args.map {
    case "" => 0
    case "true" => true
    case "false" => false
    case s: String => s.toInt
} match {
    case Array(recursiveFrom: Int, recursiveTo: Int, nonRecursiveFrom: Int, nonRecursiveTo: Int, betweenReach: Int, scoresamephrase: Boolean) =>
        RecursiveSettings(recursiveFrom, recursiveTo, nonRecursiveFrom, nonRecursiveTo, betweenReach, scoresamephrase)
}
```

You can also match on the partially provided arguments, as long as you decide which parameters will receive the default values (this case can be used alongside the "full" case match):

```
    case Array(recursiveFrom: Int, recursiveTo: Int) =>
        RecursiveSettings(recursiveFrom, recursiveTo, 0, 2, 1, true)
```

Comment: This answer was really helpful thank you. The only issue was that Array[String] didn't allow me to deal with the OP case which includes a Boolean. I've added an edit which illustrates the way I chose to deal with that. Thanks again.

Comment: I assumed `Array[String]` was the original `args` of your `main` method that you are trying to convert. If that's not the case, and you already start from a `List[Any]`, then you can get by without the `Boolean` conversions at all (leaving in just the `Int` conversion), and would `match` on a `List` instead of an `Array`; other than that, the code would be just the same

Comment: Thanks for following up. Yes, 'List[Any]' worked for me for the mixed case but then I got type errors for the pure string case. The original data come from user input via a db interface that I haven't built and are pulled down with 'Document.get()' so can be any type... That's why I opted for 'Array[_]' in the end... if that makes sense...

Comment: Makes perfect sense, as `Array[_]` is equivalent to `Array[Any]`, and is perfect for storing varying types. As for the type errors (I assume these are conversion errors for `String`s that aren't `Integer`s), you can use `scala.util.control.Exception.allCatch` to transform the `String` into an `Integer` (if it can be converted), or leave it as `String` (if it can't) in a functional way

Comment: Thanks @Alex, all of this is super helpful. Sorry I can't upvote your answer properly - waiting on enough rep! :)

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching you defined doesn't resolve to a single type:

```scala
val x = newsettings(i) match {
    case y : Int => y
    case y : Boolean => y
    case _ => 0
}
```

The result can be either `Int` or `Boolean`, therefore the type of `x` will be `AnyVal` as Scala cannot infer a single type.

**Quick (and dirty) solution**

Probably the simplest way to fix your code without modifying it much, is to explicitly cast `x` to the expected type:

```scala
i match {
    case 0 => result.recursiveFrom = x.asInstanceOf[Int]
    case 1 => result.recursiveTo = x.asInstanceOf[Int]
    case 2 => result.nonRecursiveFrom = x.asInstanceOf[Int]
    case 3 => result.nonRecursiveTo = x.asInstanceOf[Int]
    case 4 => result.betweenReach = x.asInstanceOf[Int]
    case 5 => result.scoresamephrase = x.asInstanceOf[Boolean]
  }
```

**Better solution**

I suggest you try to redesign your code with immutable data structures and try to use a more functional approach to solve your problem. This way your code will be more readable and less prone to side effects.

For example, the way you create newsettings from settings could be simplified a lot:

```scala
val settings = List("","1", "2", "0", "0", true)
val newsettings = settings map {
  case "" => 0
  case s : String => s.toInt
  case a  => a
}
```

Comment: Thanks @JakubZalas yes this has fixed the problem and I understand the reasoning, though I know that as you say, type casting in Scala is dirty. For my own learning I'd be interested to see a more elegant solution if you or anyone else has the time. Thanks again.

Comment: Happy I could help. Don't hesitate to accept the answer. I suggested one improvement which should give you an idea of where to go. I really don't know what you're trying to solve to suggest the best final solution. The best thing you could do is to try to improve your code, and ask more questions as you progress. Also, this is stackoverflow, and you should make an effort ;)

Comment: Done ;) Thanks for getting me started, in the end it was the case matching on Arrays I was looking for.